# Dúvidas sobre diferentes SDK android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android, já está publicado na Play Store, porém celulares com a versão do SDK menor que 21, não aparece quando é pesquisado. No meu projeto eu defini o minSdkVersion 21.

Quando eu mudo para um SDK menor, alguns métodos dão erros, por que ela precisa de um versão maior.

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Na maioria das vezes o próprio IDE avisa que tal método só sera utilizado a partir de tal versão. O ideal é procurar alternativas ou até mesmo deixar de oferecer alguns recursos para quem tem versões anteriores. Funciona assim. Quem tem um Android ainda com versão  2.3.3, irá deixar de desfrutar muita coisa nova que veio depois. Se você aprofundar bem na programação, talvez você consiga criar uma compatibilidade em relação as versões antigas, mas tem que haver uma razão bem específica.

Comment: A maior parte desses casos é resolvida recorrendo às [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html), quanto maior a sua versão mais compatibilidade consegue.